# Angular WebApp calling API leads to CORS blocking although using reverse proxy with allow-rule

Tags: angular, cors, traefik

I have problems with a CORS blocking.
I tried several solutions from the web (Browser security, reverse proxy), but didnt get it away.
May someone can help me.

Theres a WebApp (implemented with angular) which does some API calls. For development-use there is a self-signed-certificate. I do not have access to the API side.

At first it gets a token, and at second it uses this token to receive sensor data via another call.
Both happens using HttpClient and the post-method.

While getting the tokens works fine, I have still problems with the second call.
This is the error I receive:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my.domain.local/rest/dataQuery' from origin 'http://my.domain.local:8880' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

At first I had a similar error when getting the token. I solved that by copying the mentioned URI from the error-message into a new browser tab an accept there that I am sure of the unsecure connection.
It leads me to a page (from the webapp) telling me, that I do not have access to it (since I only places the URL and no further paramters etc.)
After this the API-call to receive a token was successful. But the next call still does not work.

Additionally I am wondering whether the reverse-proxy (traefik) is not working properly.

There I do have the following inside the proxies config (routes.toml):

```
[http.middlewares.cors.headers]
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
        Access-Control-Allow-Methods = "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
        Access-Control-Allow-Headers = "Accept,Authorization,Content-Type,DNT,Host,Keep-Alive,Origin,Referer,User-Agent,X-CSRF-Token,X-Requested-With"
```

I also recognized that it seems that the origin of the failing call uses http while the response comes from https (which is treated as another domain therefore the CORS error).

I tried different browsers and computers.

I am stuck and dont have further ideas what to do or to check.
It would be ok, to just disable this CORS checks for development purpose since on the live system there will be a full certificate.

This is how I do the API call:

```
private CLIENT_ID = 'my-api';
  private SECRET = 'w231wfsdf-sf23d1sfsdf-sdfs2fd1-sdfsdf';
  private BASE_URL = 'my.domain.local';
  private REALM = 'Myrealm';
  private AUTH_URL = 'https://' + this.BASE_URL + '/auth/realms/' + this.REALM + '/protocol/bla/token';
  private API_URL = 'https://' + this.BASE_URL + '/rest/dataQuery';
```

get token:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  })
};

const body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&' + 'client_id=' + this.CLIENT_ID + '&client_secret=' + this.SECRET;

return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.AUTH_URL, body, httpOptions)
```

get sensor data:

```
return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.API_URL, theApiParams, httpOptions);const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
    };

    const pp = JSON.stringify(param);
```

Any help or tips would be grateful. Thanks.

Edit:
After checking trafik.docs again I changed my config in the routes.toml to this:

```
[http.middlewares.cors.headers]
    accessControlAllowOrigins = "*"
    accessControlAllowMethods = ["GET", "OPTIONS", "POST"]
    accessControlAllowHeaders = ["Accept,Authorization,Content-Type,DNT,Host,Keep-Alive,Origin,Referer,User-Agent,X-CSRF-Token,X-Requested-With"]
```

But it didnt work either. Maybe I am missreading the docs, I have difficulties to understand it. It is not written clear.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: I got further into analysis. Since I can see the post-request (both for token an for dataQuery) in the dev-console of the browser, it means that the browser is running that peace of code. So I guess every code written in angular is sent to the browser to be executed there? Cant find sufficient info on angulars website about this. This is kind of a design problem of my application. I need to change these API-calls to reach an endpoint within the web-app (angular) where then angular redirects these API-calls to the very back-end. But how to write Code in Angular that is not executed in browser?